# Не могу понять чего не хватает, мне нужно копировать несколько строк из таблицы исходя из выбранных checkbox

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Не могу понять чего не хватает в коде, мне нужно копировать несколько строк из таблицы исходя из выбранных `checkbox`, для обработки данных у меня есть массив `checkbox` он называется `abs`.
Вот код копирования на `php`. Условие поясню, если нажата кнопка `copypast` и в массиве abs выбраны `checkbox` то выполняется условие, копируются строки в таблице, я не могу связать с массивом `abs checkbox`

```
 if (isset($_POST['copypast']) and(!empty($_POST['abs']))) {
     $id = $_POST['id'];
     $result = $dbh - > query("SELECT * FROM tovars WHERE id=$id") - > fetch();
     $result['flag'] = 0;
     $result['id'] = 0;
     foreach($result as $k = > $v) {
         $fields[] = $k;
         $vals[] = "'$v'";
     }
     $fields1 = implode(", ", $fields);
     $vals1 = implode(", ", $vals);
     $q = "INSERT INTO tovars  (".$fields1.
     ") VALUES (".$vals1.
     ")";
     $query = $dbh - > prepare($q);
     $query - > execute();
 } else {
     echo "не работает";
 }
```

форма с таблицой есть
http://jsfiddle.net/gxpfo5j8/

не дописал, при копировании несколько строк эти строки должны вставляться в таблицу, выше код работает только если например на каждой строке есть кнопка и при нажатии на нее будет копироваться одна строка,а мне нужно чтобы копировалось несколько строк. Подскажите как можно реализовать

Answer (score 1):

Оберните всю таблицу в форму:

```
<form>
    <table>
        <tr>
             <th>тескт</th> 
             <th><input type= checkbox name = "abs<?php echo $id ?>" ></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
             <th>тескт</th> 
             <th><input type= checkbox name = "abs<?php echo $id ?>" ></th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

дальше на `php` в цикле Вытаскиваешь `ID`  и сверяешь с `"abs<?php echo $id ?>"`

Comment: Если не знал: тут можно редактировать текст вопроса, не писать в комментах то что не дописал

Comment: я тут совсем не давно, так что не знал как это сделать)

Comment: кнопка "править" под вопросом

Comment: Нашел, спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему, написал один запрос, пример: INSERT INTO (pole1, pole2) SELECT (pole1, pole2) под копирование строк в таблице и все заработало.